# An example to illustrate the: "Coding is just abstracted p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m solving" point to a complete layman?

Tags: logic

I was talking to someone in a bar not too long ago, and the inevitable question of "What do you do?" Came up. My response "Oh, I just recently graduated; I work in company X. I'm a programmer" didn't quite satisfy her.

I've had this conversation a hundred times and people are never quite happy with the answer. They always have more questions. I think this is because, for the mostpart, people don't really know what a programmer *does*. The answer to this question normally gives you an insight into a person (sort of): Accountants might be analytical and good with numbers, lawyers might be good with words and debate etc. 'programmer' doesn't.

so I tried to give an answer that would give that sort of insight.

I tried to illustrate my point of "Well It's basically fancy problem solving" with an example of a classic programming problem.

The first thing that jumped into my head (for some reason) was the smallest subset problem... but I'd have to explain arrays, time complexity, etc
I thought of n-queens problem, but she'd never seen a chessboard in her life (yeah, I know)
Towers of hanoi was too hard to envision in general...

So I Was stuck and the topic changed.

Can you guys think of an example of a problem; that a complete lay(wo)man can understand, which would give someone an idea of the kind of thinking programmers have to do? (and by extension save me answering awkward questions about how I make my living)

Comment: I've given up trying to explain what I do for a living. Tbh - if you're in a bar, talking to a woman, avoid talking about anything remotely connected to IT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get asked what I do too, and basically, all I say is that You wouldn't understand much about it, which will get you one of two responses: "Try me" and shes interested ->move to next section of comment, or she will just shut down and think that you think she's not intelligent. USE WITH DISCRETION.

Now, if she says try me, you have a challenge. Obviously what you do is going to be over her head, but you know you can explain a little to her. Basically, what I try to explain is that I am a logician, kinda like a magician. When the computer needs to be told to do something, and no one else knows how to tell it, they call me up. Sometimes it's simple, other times, its likes climbing Mt. Everest with your fingers on some impossibly difficult task. Imagine the worlds largest word search, and you don't know what words you're looking for. That's what I do. I find those words. So as you could imagine, I'm quick to notice little things and remember them. ;)

That should elicit the kind of response out of any women worth your time. 
Good Luck!